# NodeJS Process Uploaded file with readline

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting a file the client uploads which I receive with the following route:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var file = req.files.file;

    //Process file inline
    funcs.Process(file, req).then((data)=>{
        //res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.txt');
        res.write(data, 'binary');
        res.end();
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.redirect('/?err='+err);
    });

});
```

This is the code for `funcs.Process`:

```
Process: function(file, req){


    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(file)
        });

        var output = "";

        lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
            //some checks
            ProcessLine(line).then((data)=>{
                output += data + "\n";
            }).catch((err)=>{
                reject(`Invalid line in file [${line}].`);
            });
        });

        lineReader.on('close', () => {
            resolve(output);
        });

    });
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer,

produced by the readline `input: fs.createReadStream(file)`

As this is an uploaded file, how do I use it in the readline `createInterface`?

Comment: Does req.files.file has a value or is undefined?

Comment: I don't see any validation on the post.

Comment: Are you using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for the file upload handling?

Comment: @WarleyNoleto yes, it has a value. I tested console.log(req.files.file) and I do get contents.

Comment: @Vasan I am using express-fileupload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) accepts a string path.

You're passing it `req.files.file`, which is the [file object](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload#user-content-example-scenario) created by `express-fileupload`.

You have two options:

1. Use the `mv` function (`req.files.file.mv('<path>', callbackFunc)`) to first move the file to a known path on your server. Then pass this known path to `fs.createReadStream`.
2. Create the read stream directly from the file data buffer exposed in `req.files.file.data` using [streamifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamifier) or similar library.

`var fileStream = require('streamifier').createReadStream(req.files.file.data)`

This stream can then be passed to `readline` as input directly.